# Vimperator: Can not send comment on Facebook anymore

Tags: facebook, firefox-addon, vimperator

I can not send any comment on Facebook, when my Vimperator-Plugin is active. This happens in Firefox 33.1.1 and Vimperator 3.8.3.

By clicking in the comment field, the INSERT-Mode is activated and I can type my comment, but hitting the Enter-Key doesn't send the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[disable Vimperator temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271624/disable-vimperator-temporarily)

What I do is temporarily disable Vimperator by shift+esc. And re-enable it by typing it again.

Comment: So do you have the same problem, as described?

Comment: This works as described: Shift+Esc OR Insert to disable temporary Vimperator and the same keys for activating it again.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a fix for this bug. Just download the latest unreleased xpi from here:

https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/releases/tag/3.8.3-a5